# Formula created with ClosedXML not recognized in Excel

Tags: vb.net, excel, closedxml

So far I've been exporting data to Excel using the Microsoft.Office.Interop library. Now I need instead to do it using ClosedXML. Everything works fine except for the formulas. Each formula itself is exported properly, however it doesn't "work" until I doubleclick its content and press enter. I attach a screenshot to clarify this.

[image]

Note: the range (P2:P3) in the image is black until I click it and becomes blue. This somehow makes Excel recognize the content.

Previously I was using:

```
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop
worksheet.Cells(i, j).FormulaLocal = "=SUMA(" & col_letter & "2:" & col_letter & rowcount & ")"
```

Now I'm using:

```
Imports ClosedXML.Excel
                worksheet.Cell(i, j).SetFormulaA1("SUMA(" & col_letter & "2:" & col_letter & rowcount  & ")")
```

It is so simple that I'm completely stuck.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I wonder if ClosedXML only works with the English formula names... you could try `SUM` instead of `SUMA` and see if that helps.

Comment: Damn it! it was so simple... Thanks for your suggestion @Mark, you made my day

Comment: Cool - it seems like this may be something that others would run into, so I'll add an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I can't find any documentation to confirm this, I suspect that ClosedXML only works with the English formula names, so use `SUM` instead of `SUMA`:

```
worksheet.Cell(i, j).SetFormulaA1("SUM(" & col_letter & "2:" & col_letter & rowcount  & ")")
```